# How can I allow a polymer component to contain dynamic elements?

Tags: polymer

In polymer, let's say I have a container element `<x-container>`, and two child elements `<a-child>`, `<b-child>`. In an  element, I want to be able to specify that it contains either `<a-child>` or `<b-child>` (it will never have both).

For example, it could look like:

`1. <x-container><a-child></a-child></x-container>`

or,

`2. <x-container><b-child></b-child></x-container>`.

Since `<x-container>` has a lot of code, I don't want to duplicate it, but want to be able to use an `<x-container>` like this:

`<x-container type = 'a-child'></x-container>` which would then have the same behavior as the first item mentioned. How could I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instanciate it when you have the information which one its going to be!

```
//in your x-container component
observers: ['_typeChanged(type)'],
_typeChanged: function(type) {
    var child = this.create(type);
    Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(child);
}
```

Or you use a slot then you could do smth like this

parent component

```
<x-container>
   <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isA()]]"><a-child></a-child></template>
   <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isB()]]"><b-child></b-child></template>
</x-container>
```

and in your x-container´s template just simply put a slot the child will be rendered within the slot

```
<slot></slot>
```

Comment: I personally prefer the the first option